# How to retrieve document from collection if the ObjectId is null?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `FormSubmissions` and `SubmissionLogs`

`FormSubmissions` schema has following record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56bc8b9b16f0172828f951"),
    "LanguageId" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"),
    "FolderName" : "89cd1929-bff9-9a6c-a60b-08bec5966d13",
    "IsSync" : false,
    "UpdatedBy" : 0,
    "IsCompleted" : true,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5ac5b80b19e1011e64766698"),
    "Longitude" : null,
    "Latitude" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "null",
    "AppInfoId" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56c06a9b16f0172828f956"),
    "LanguageId" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"),
    "FolderName" : "05f79cc4-ae85-7bab-4882-9dac416063f9",
    "IsSync" : false,
    "UpdatedBy" : 0,
    "IsCompleted" : true,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "Longitude" : null,
    "Latitude" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "null",
    "AppInfoId" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56ef414efb640d104105f9"),
    "LanguageId" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"),
    "FolderName" : "d7219aff-3b8d-2931-8ca7-b790e0d1b1f4",
    "IsSync" : false,
    "UpdatedBy" : 0,
    "IsCompleted" : true,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "Longitude" : null,
    "Latitude" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "null",
    "AppInfoId" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56ef4d4efb640d104105fd"),
    "LanguageId" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"),
    "FolderName" : "ca213664-976e-8c5d-6d3c-272931ad2dfa",
    "IsSync" : false,
    "UpdatedBy" : 0,
    "IsCompleted" : true,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "Longitude" : null,
    "Latitude" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "null",
    "AppInfoId" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b595c2999c26d061ceff3d1"),
    "LanguageId" : ObjectId("5a6304ffc3c3f119fc0e60c9"),
    "FolderName" : "cde6767f-ebf2-6892-97d8-d8c9339b389d",
    "IsSync" : false,
    "UpdatedBy" : 0,
    "IsCompleted" : true,
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "EmployeeId" : null,
    "Longitude" : null,
    "Latitude" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "null",
    "AppInfoId" : null,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

`SubmissionLogs` schema has following record

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56bc8c9b16f0172828f954"),
    "FormId" : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948"),
    "SubmissionId" : ObjectId("5b56bc8b9b16f0172828f951"),
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5ac5b80b19e1011e64766698"),
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:43:40.290Z"),
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:43:40.290Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56c06b9b16f0172828f959"),
    "FormId" : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948"),
    "SubmissionId" : ObjectId("5b56c06a9b16f0172828f956"),
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T06:00:11.449Z"),
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T06:00:11.449Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56ef414efb640d104105fc"),
    "FormId" : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948"),
    "SubmissionId" : ObjectId("5b56ef414efb640d104105f9"),
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:20:01.930Z"),
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:20:01.930Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56ef4d4efb640d10410600"),
    "FormId" : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948"),
    "SubmissionId" : ObjectId("5b56ef4d4efb640d104105fd"),
    "EmployeeId" : ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"),
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:20:13.948Z"),
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:20:13.948Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b595c2999c26d061ceff3d4"),
    "FormId" : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948"),
    "SubmissionId" : ObjectId("5b595c2999c26d061ceff3d1"),
    "EmployeeId" : null,
    "UpdatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-26T05:29:13.991Z"),
    "CreatedOn" : ISODate("2018-07-26T05:29:13.991Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want only that SubmissionLogs which i'm passing EmployeeId (in array-null also)

for that i'm doing this,

```
db.FormSubmissions.aggregate(
    [{
            $match : {
                $and : [{
                        FormId : ObjectId("5b56bbb19b16f0172828f948")
                    }, {
                        IsDeleted : false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : "SubmissionLogs",
                localField : "_id",
                foreignField : "SubmissionId",
                as : "SubmissionLogs"
            }
        }, {
            $addFields : {
                SubmissionLog : {
                    $filter : {
                        input : "$SubmissionLogs",
                        as : "submissionLogs_field",
                        cond : {
                            $setIsSubset : [
                                ["$$submissionLogs_field.EmployeeId"],
                                ["5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d", null]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                SubmissionLog : "$SubmissionLog"
            }
        }
    ]).pretty()
```

I want only that records which have `["5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d", null]` EmployeeId in `SubmissionLogs`.I also want that records if EmployeeId has null.

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: @anthony-winzlet its 3.6

Comment: Have you tried the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine  [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)  [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
db.FormSubmissions.aggregate([
    {
        $match : { IsDeleted : false}
    }, 
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "SubmissionLogs",
            localField : "_id",
            foreignField : "SubmissionId",
            as : "SubmissionLogs"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind" : "$SubmissionLogs"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {"SubmissionLogs.EmployeeId" : {"$in" : [ObjectId("5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d"), null]}}
    },
    {"$group" : {"_id" : "$_id",SubmissionLog : {"$push" : "$SubmissionLogs"}}}
])
```

Comment: i am passing `["5b56bc429b16f0172828f94d", null]` is not fixed,its coming dynamic. May be its three or four ids..I am passing that array from method.so how can i write `$or` condition here